# getc(stdin) returns two characters. Is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: c

I am currently using `getc()` in a loop to receive input from a user:

```
char x;
while (x != 'q')
{    
 printf("(c)ontinue or (q)uit?");
 x = getc(stdin);
}
```

If the user enters `c` the loop executes, presumably taking an additional character (the terminator or possibly a newline, I am guessing?) as input the first time around.

I can prevent this by using something like:

```
char toss;
char x;
while (x != 'q')
{    
 printf("(c)ontinue or (q)uit?");
 x = getc(stdin);
 toss = getc(stdin);
}
```

But this strikes me as just a lazy newbie way of dealing with it. Is there a cleaner way to do this with `getc` or should I be using it as a string and using the first character of the array? Is there another even cleaner way that I haven't even considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> or should I be using it as a string and using the first character of the array?

Exactly.

```
char buf[32] = { 0 };

while (buf[0] != 'q') {
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    /* do stuff here */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just ignore spaces:

```
int x = 0;
while (x != 'q' && x != EOF)
{    
 printf("(c)ontinue or (q)uit?");
 while ((x = getc(stdin)) != EOF && isspace(x)) { /* ignore whitespace */ }
}
```

Also note that `getc()` returns an `int`, not `char`. This is important if you want to detect `EOF` which you should also check for to avoid an infinite loop (for example if the user hits Ctrl-D on unix systems or Ctrl-Z on windows). To use `isspace()` you will need to include ctype.h.